# Blazor HTML Rendering Issue

Tags: html, blazor

I'm not sure how to best explain this because I'm a desktop app developer just starting in web. It seems that Blazor is turning carriage returns in the .razor file into elements in the html rendering. I've noticed this for a while now but these elements didn't seem to affect anything. Well I came across a situation where they are affecting my layout. If you look at my screenshot you will see in this page control I made there is a space between the Next and Last buttons. My other screenshot shows the html elements that get rendered and you see a < !-- !--> between those buttons. Also those elements seem to be all over the place. Through some testing I realize that it's the carriage return in the html code in the .razor file. As you can see I put the First and Prev buttons on one line of code but the Next and Last buttons are on 2 lines.

[Page Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhvRY.png)

[Html Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc78L.png)

```
<div class="my-2">
<button disabled="@(CurrentPage==1)" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary py-0 px-1" style="font-size: small; font-family: Webdings;" @onclick="First_Click">&#57;</button><button disabled="@(CurrentPage==1)" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary py-0 px-1" style="font-size: small; font-family: Webdings;" @onclick="Prev_Click">&#51;</button>

@for (int i = 1; i <= TotalPages; i++)
{
    int x = i;
    <button disabled="@(CurrentPage==i)" class="btn btn-sm @(CurrentPage==i ? "btn-primary" : "btn-outline-primary") py-0 px-1" style="font-size: small; font-family: Courier;" @onclick="()=>Page_Click(x)">@i</button>
}

<button disabled="@(CurrentPage==TotalPages)" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary py-0 px-1" style="font-size: small; font-family: Webdings;" @onclick="Next_Click">&#52;</button>
<button disabled="@(CurrentPage==TotalPages)" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary py-0 px-1" style="font-size: small; font-family: Webdings;" @onclick="Last_Click">&#58;</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you appear to be using Bootstrap, try using a `ButtonGroup` [link here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/button-group/) as a wrapper for the buttons.  I have seen a similar issue before.

I've included an image of buttons within a button group in action in one of my applications

[image]

If you want some more detail come back to me and I'll point you to some code in a repository.

Comment: Thank you Shaun. It did solve the layout issue with my buttons and they look cleaner now too. It still has those garbage html elements ( < !--!--> ) though . I'm curious to see if anyone knows where they come from and if they have any purpose.

Comment: The comments appear in the HTML because the internal JS algorithm uses them to map the component structure from the Blazor representation to the one in the page. Comments are needed to avoid introducing artificial elements to delimit the start and end of components.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21526) for details.

Comment: @MarkGrecco Further to Shaun Curtis' answer, the reason you're only seeing whitespace between the final two buttons is because these are the only two buttons you have a carriage return between (at least in the example you've provided). The browser would render this.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and the link. That explains it well